# How to use git to split part of the code from the original branch as a new branch

Tags: git, gitlab

During project development, different functions of the same branch must be launched in batches，how to use git to split part of the code from the original branch as a new branch

how to use git to split part of the code from the original branch as a new branch

Comment: And do you want to keep the original branch _as is_ or you would like to remove the parts that you moved into the other branch?

Comment: Reference to `git add -p` incoming in 5... 4... 3.... (or maybe `git stash -p`?)

Comment: wait and see, wait and see.

Comment: you could use the `git stash` command https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

in this way

`git stash branch <new-branch> stash@{n}`

the command creates the new branch `new-branch` with your changes

Comment: @MicheleDeFalco The general process is good, but it will take every pending change into the new branch. Use `-p` when stashing to have git interactively display changes chunk by chunk for you to choose what to take or not.

Comment: Now that I have pushed to the remote branch, I want to split out two branches from the remote development branch

Comment: @shoanjen If you already have an (unsplitted) version of the branch on the remote, you'll eventually have to force-push to overwrite the obsolete remote ref when all is sorted out locally and you're happy with your result.

Comment: Do you mean that you want some commits in one branch and other commits in other, or is this rather on a file content level?

Comment: yes.Now I have a feat branch, and I want to separate part of the feature code from the feat branch as feat_step1 branch, and other feature code as feat_step2 branch

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it is by taking advantage of `git reset --soft`.

So.... suppose you have this:

```
* bbb (branch1) a big change
* aaa (main) main branch
```

So, we want to break up changes from `branch1` into a separate `branch2`.... so, we start by setting `branch2` is and doing a soft reset to `main`:

```
git checkout -b branch2 branch1
git reset --soft main
```

At this moment, you have this:

```
* bbb (branch1) a big change
* aaa (main, branch2 -> HEAD) main branch
```

The important part is that the current working tree has the same content of `branch1`..... so feel free to pick the pieces you like from the files and add them to index (with `git add -p` for example) or edit the files and leave them the way you want to have them then add them to index.... and finally, do the commit.... at this point you have:

```
* ccc (branch2 -> HEAD) only some changes we want to get from branch1
| * bbb (branch1) a big change
|/
* aaa (main) main branch
```

You can still add more commits with other partial changes on top of `branch2` but the easiest way is with `restore` at this point.... so you do, still on `branch2`:

```
git restore --source branch1 -- .
```

You again get the full content of `branch1` and so you edit the files and add them to index, then commit.... and repeat the 4 operations (`git restore; edit files; git add; git commit;`) for as many commits as you need.... so, you could end up with this:

```
* eee (branch2 -> HEAD) yet another part
* ddd another part
* ccc only some changes we want to get from branch1
| * bbb (branch1) a big change
|/
* aaa (main) main branch
```

Until you get all the changes of `branch1` into `branch2`.

Comment: How did I not see `reset --soft` coming? :-) Excellent answer.

Comment: Nowadays, restore can do the whole thing.... _but_ I would miss `git reset --soft` </3 :'( :-D

Comment: Now that I have pushed to the remote branch, I want to split out two branches from the remote development branch

Comment: **What** have you pushed? And the fact that something is pushed makes no difference in terms of splitting into separate branches.... it would be relevant if you mean to put something _different_ into that remote branch cause you might need to force-push.